# JQuery can not get the right value by val() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form like this

```js
$('#email').on('keyup', function() {
  console.clear();
  console.log($('#email').val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required id="email">
```

and I want to get the value of Email input, so I use this `$("#email").val()` .
But I find this just working in English not in Chinese.
If I input "33333@去.com" in to the email input, the code will give this value:"33333@xn--1nr.com".
I can not get the point to fix it.This is not utf-8 of unicode.I even not see any of this before.

[image]

Comment: Please show us your jquery, because when I use `$("#email").val()` on `33333@去.com` then it returns `33333@去.com`

Comment: Make sure to use UTF-8 or a comparable encoding. This can be made sure in the http headers: Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen  client seems to be right:- https://jsfiddle.net/tpqq7j1t/

Comment: @AlivetoDie I'm not facing the problem here on StackOverflow, Might be related to mbadeveloper's surgestion.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen  even on StackOverflow i have faced the same issue. Since I cannot post it an answer I created a fiddle for this...

Comment: @AlivetoDie Very wierd, I ran the same code in the snippet editor and everything works at it shall

Comment: Didn't work for me (locally, stackoverflow)

Comment: I got one solution and it worked by change google translator to chines.

Comment: Tried it with vanilla JS, but still not working.

Comment: check this link:
http://prntscr.com/jlkicx

Comment: Ok, I did a test with browsers: Chrome(), Firefox(), Opera(), IE11(), Edge(). Maybe because Chrome and Opera both use blink rendering engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't matter.

`xn--1nr.com` is the [IDNA Punycode](https://www.punycoder.com/) encoding for `去.com` – after all, if you send mail to `33333@去.com`, you will actually end up sending mail to `33333@xn--1nr.com`.

The browser is trying to be clever for you by normalizing the value to Punycode since the field is an email field.

Comment: so you mean that there is no chinese idn right? All idn is code by unicode?

Comment: All IDNs are stored as Punycode ASCII, yes. There's nothing specific about Chinese/CJK characters in IDNs.